# Python group and sub variable (parent and child variable)

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.4, cobol

I am a COBOL developer and have learned Python recently.

I would like to know what is the Python equivalent of record-layouts in COBOL, as I am looking at preparing code converter from COBOL to Python. COBOL record-layouts look like this.

```
01  GRP-VAR. 
       05  GRP-1. 
              10  G1-VAR-1      PIC X(10).
              10  G2-VAR-2      PIC X(40).
       05  GRP-2. 
              10  G2-VAR-1      PIC 9(4). 
              10  G2-VAR-2      PIC 9(20).
```

I know in python we don't have to explicitly define variables, but we can. What I would like to accomplish in python is, as below.

---

```
VarA = " Test A"
VarB = " Test B"
VarC = # some statement(s) that Make VarA and VarB child of VarC. Not (VarA+VarB)
Print (VarC) # This will print " Test A Test B"
VarB = " Test X"
print (VarC) # This should print " Test A Test X" instead of " Test A Test B"
```

To dynamically change the content of Parent variable VarC, when VarA or VarB change its contents in the program.

Comment: can you better explain how would you like to use this in python.

Comment: Please **edit this question**, rather than asking the same thing again

Comment: Sure I though my 1st question did not publish. Thanks

Comment: In python I would like to see if we can accomplish relationship between variables.  So that changing child variable will reflect in parent and other way round. Thank You

Comment: can you write example of what would you do and what  you expect to happen.

Comment: there is module [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html) for extracting data from binary data-

Comment: No my problem is not with type of data. Letter me give an example...

Comment: VARA = "testA” ;   VARB = " testB" ; VARC = VARA + VARB;   print (VARC) VARB = "testX"; print (VARC)   I would like VARC to change when we change VARB dynamically.

Comment: That's not going to happen without significant changes (either modifying Python itself or making your own custom string-y object); strings are immutable, and the result of `VARA + VARB` creates a new object completely unrelated to either of the input strings.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in python to *Cobol*'s group structure is a [class](https://www.google.com/search?q=object%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=object%20definition%20python)

your Cobol example in Python becomes:

```
 class grp1:
   def __init__(self):
      self.v1 = "asd"     
      self.v2 = "qwerty"

   def text(self):
       return self.v1 + self.v2

 class grpvar:
   def __init__(self):
       self.g1 = grp1()
       self.g2 = grp1()

   def text(self):
      return self.g1.text() + self.g2.text()

 myvar = grpvar()

 myvar.g2.v1 = "wsxedc"

 print "d) " + myvar.text()
```

is roughly equivalent to the *Cobol*. If you want to read/write like you do cobol you need to write encode/decode methods.

---

To give the same functionality as Cobol-IO, have a look at [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf)
or [avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/gettingstartedpython.html). You will need to more experience in python before trying these packages

---

If you want to **read/write Cobol files**, there is [stingray](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stingrayreader/?source=directory), I have never tried it

alternatively if you use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), you can access the Java/Cobol libraries